# Android Studio viewFlipper Crashing App

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I'm making an application. I have succeeded in creating a viewFlipper with:

- android:flipInterval="5000"
- android:autoStart="true"

I've also made two buttons, next and previous, with:

- android:clickable="true"
- android:onClick="onClick"

I want each button to affect the ViewFlipper, as in when the next button is pressed, the next image is displayed. And, when the previous button is pressed, the previous image is displayed.

What do I need to add to the XML file and what do I need to add to the MainActivity class? Everything I've tried up until now either prevents the app opening or crashes the app when the button is pressed.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.